# Pressing Submit Button on Post Form Only Reloads the Page

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need to post values from an HTML form but every time I press the submit button the page reloads, and that's it. I've checked the routes and controller, and everything seems fine to me.

**Blade**

```php
<div class="panel-body">
    @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    @foreach($users as $users)
        @if(session("admin")==0)
            Meno: {{$users["name"]}} Email: {{$users["email"]}}
            Registrovaný: {{$users["created_at"]}}
        @endif
        @if(session("admin")==1 AND $users["admin"]==0)
            <form action="/promote" method="POST">
                Meno: {{$users["name"]}} Email: {{$users["email"]}}
                Registrovaný: {{$users["created_at"]}}
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$users["id"]}}">
                <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-green">Promote</button>
            </form>@endif
        @if(session("admin")==1 AND $users["admin"]==1)
            <form action="/demote" method="POST">
                Meno: {{$users["name"]}} Email: {{$users["email"]}}
                Registrovaný: {{$users["created_at"]}}
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$users["id"]}}">
                <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-red">Demote</button>
            </form>@endif
        <br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::post('/promote', 'users_controller@promote')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/demote', 'users_controller@demote')->middleware('auth');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function promote(Request $req)
{
    $id = $req->input('id');
    DB::table('users')->where("id", $id)->update(["admin" => 1]);

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function demote(Request $req)
{
    $id = $req->input('id');
    DB::table('users')->where("id", $id)->update(["admin" => 0]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I want to change the database value on column "admin" on a row with the id posted in a hidden input. Now it doesn't do anything but reload the page.

Comment: This gives you any error in the console? Also, put @csrf into your form tag.

Comment: No ... console showing normal stuff like loading favicon etc.

Comment: Adding {{csrf_field()}} solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: I'm happy to help. I wrote an answer, I would appreciate it if you accepted it as the correct answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the CSRF token, to solve this you should put `@csrf` inside your form tag, like:

```
<form action="/demote" method="POST">
      @csrf
      Meno: {{$users["name"]}} Email: {{$users["email"]}}
      Registrovaný: {{$users["created_at"]}}
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$users["id"]}}">
      <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-red">Demote</button>
</form>
```

For more info check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf)

Answer (score 0):

To submit the form you would most likely need to use `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` instead off `<button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-red">Demote</button>`.

This has caused issues for me before using plain HTML and PHP, give it a try.

Comment: A submit type button works just as well as a submit type input